# Renaming start of all file names in folder before first underscore

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, command

In a batch file i would like to rename the start of all files in one folder, the files at the moment are named as such

1_sometext 
2_sometext
...
467_sometext

this is causing a problem where I need these files to appear in the correct order when calling dir on the directory

i would like them to appear like 
001_sometext
002_sometext
003_sometext
...
467_sometext

this way they will always appear in order when i need them

how could this be done in a batch file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will rename your files as you want :

```
@echo off
set YOUR_DIR=%1
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set temp_str=something
for /f "tokens=*" %%L in ('dir /b %YOUR_DIR%' ) do (
      set INITIAL_NAME=%%L
       for /f "tokens=1 delims=_" %%a in ("%%L") do (
            set INTEGER_PART=%%a
            SET temp_str=!INTEGER_PART!
        )

         call :GET_STR_LEN
         if "!str_len!"=="1" (
            set PREFIX=00
         ) else (
             if "!str_len!"=="2" (
                 set PREFIX=0
              ) else (
                   set PREFIX=
                )

             ) 


        pushd %YOUR_DIR%
        echo The file is %%L
        set NEW_NAME=!PREFIX!%%L
        echo The new name is !NEW_NAME!
        REN "%%L" "!NEW_NAME!"
        popd

    )

:GET_STR_LEN
SET /a str_len=0

:loop
if defined temp_str (
SET temp_str=!temp_str:~1!
SET /A str_len=str_len+1
GOTO loop
)

exit /b
```

Place this in a batch file called rename_files.bat and execute it as :
rename_files "your_dir"

Comment: That's perfect, Thank you!